# how to use if contions in update statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

i need to use if condition in update query,please check and let me know the below update statement
will work fine??

```
if opt=1 then
update EOD SET  flag='Y' where Step_name='STEP_1'
else if
ip opt=2 then
update EOD SET  flag='Y' where Step_name='STEP_2'
end if;

'''
```

Comment: What is `opt`? Is this really a PL/SQL problem, or is it something that could / should be done in a single `insert` statement (plain SQL, no PL/SQL code)?

Comment: opt-- is a input parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with where clause.

```
update EOD SET  flag='Y' where (Step_name=STEP_1 and opt=1) or(Step_name=STEP_2 and opt=2);
```

To do it in PL/SQL as you intended instead of `else if` you need to use `elseif`:

```
if opt=1 then
update EOD SET  flag='Y' where Step_name=STEP_1;

elseif opt=2 then
update EOD SET  flag='Y' where Step_name=STEP_2;
end if;
```

Comment: opt is not a column name,it is a input parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE
    OR REPLACE PROCEDURE archana (opt IN NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
    IF opt = 1 THEN
        UPDATE EOD SET FLAG = 'Y' WHERE STEP_NAME = 'STEP_1';
    ELSIF opt = 2 THEN
        UPDATE EOD SET FLAG = 'Y' WHERE STEP_NAME = 'STEP_2';
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('ERROR');
    END IF;
END;
```

opt is accepted as input parameter then based on the value corresponding update queries are executed. P.S: kindly test your code before posting in this forum instead of asking whether it will work. if its not working then many peeps are here to help.

Comment: Are you sure that your code is working ? You have only 1 END IF and 2 IFs !

Comment: I have edited now ELSE IF to ELSIF. I hope ELSIF will do the job without multiple ENDIF.